# SQL Server Stored Proc - What is returned to a variable if no data?

Tags: sql-server

If, using the following code in a MS SQL Server 2008 stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @PROD_ID VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT @PROD_ID = MYTABLE.PROD 
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE MYTABLE.DEVID = @DEVCODE
```

DEVCODE does not exist, what will PROD_ID contain? I've tried printing it, but it prints what seems to be a space. However, testing it for space fails. Also, testing for NULL fails. OR, should I be testing for empty in a different manner?

Thanks for reading
BBz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the @DEVCODE id doesn't exist then @PROD_ID will remain null.

You can't use COALESCE or ISNULL inside the SELECT @PROD_ID = ... statement because it won't return any records at all.

However, you can do:

```
DECLARE @PROD_ID VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @PROD_ID = MYTABLE.PROD 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYTABLE.DEVID = @DEVCODE

IF (@PROD_ID is null) BEGIN
  -- do something
END
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. Something so simple to overlook too :s

Answer (score 1):

`@PROD_ID` should remain NULL if `@DEVCODE` does not exist.

Are you testing appropriately using

```
...@PROD_ID IS NULL...
```

and not trying to test

```
...@PROD_ID = NULL...
```

which would be incorrect?

Comment: No I wasn't, I was trying to use '='.  Many thanks for the pointer!